# Why do questions without recent activity show as modified by Community?

Tags: support, status-completed

I've seen this a few time lately and I'm curious if there's a reason for it or if it's a bug.

On the front page (questions by active), [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66567/how-to-manage-the-osmosis-filters) shows that it was modified by Community recently:
[image]

However, there doesn't seem to be any modifications since 2013...is this a bug? Or did something like a user deletion trigger this?

Comment: Thanks for asking about this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Basically the system looks for questions that have at least one answer but none that are accepted or upvoted. It then performs a 'non-edit' to bump them to the top of the active view with the hope they attract attention and get 'resolved'. It's basically the system trying to clear the Unanswered view - an upvote on any answer removes it from that category, even if not accepted.

---

Here's a SE Meta post that has the details: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

> • The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that
>   have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that.
>
> • Questions are picked randomly from the top-viewed inactive questions.
>
> • The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the
>   site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 1 per hour on Meta, and 2 per hour
>   on Super User and Server Fault. The default for a new site is 1 per
>   hour.

More info about the Community user can be found at [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)